# Are there well-known properties of bisymmetric matrices with a constant diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An example of a bisymmetric matrix with constant diagonal is
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\
b & a & d & c \\
c & d & a & b \\
d & c& b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$
Is there a special name for such matrices? And, are there any well-known properties of such matrices?

Comment: No. See the wikipedia on bisymmetric matrices for an example of a general form. @coiso